# a good profiler for nhibernate logs?

Tags: nhibernate

Hi I have a web application with nhibernate talking to the database.

The application is running very slow due to lot of chatty db calls that nhibernate is doing.
I want to run a profiler or something similar that can give some stats example

1. number of db trips.
2. table names and times accessed.

I saw one of the products called nhprof . I am wondering if there is something open source or free available out there or some other technique that i can use to meet the goal here.

Edit: I am using SQL Server 2005 .

Comment: NHProf has free trial of 30 days...doesn't hurt to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know the 2 things you mention, you can create a log4net appender to find the information you want. I use a http module that adds the query information to the html in a web application when running in debug mode. If you want real statistics or more information than in the example, nhprof might be worth the money.

Comment: can you hint which appender to user to count the db connections and number of times a table is hit ?

Comment: Any appender can be used, its the actual logger that you need that I think you need.

Comment: NHibernate perf HttpModule sample: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/07/MeasuringNHibernatesQueriesPerPage.aspx

Comment: NHibernate Statistics sample: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/26/exploring-nhibernate-statistics-part-1-simple-data-fetching.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The NHibernate statistics are available as `ISessionFactory.Statistics` and `ISession.Statistics`. For the basic stats you describe, this

That said, NHProf does more and is well worth the price.